# Python3 import - running local vs from pip discrepancy

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have a small pip-package (let's call it my_package) that I wrote in python3 with the following directory structure. I am confused as to a discrepancy I'm seeing in running `my_package.py` locally vs when I'm testing it by downloading it from PyPI, importing it into some other code, and then running it.

```
.
|  README.md
|  LICENSE
|  setup.py
|  build
|  dist
|  my_package
|  -- __init__.py
|  -- my_package.py
|  -- helpers
|  ---- __init__.py
|  ---- helper1.py
|  ---- helper2.py
|  ---- helper3.py
|  ---- helper4.py
```

In `my_package.py` I have the following imports:

```
from helpers import helper1
from helpers import helper2
from helpers import helper3
from helpers import helper4
```

Obviously these are just filler names, but the point remains that I am trying to import some code from the helpers directory from the `my_package.py` script.

If I were to run my_package.py locally my code executes without any issue - I think this is the expected behavior for python3. However, if I upload this to PyPI and then import the package, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import my_package
  File "/Users/fakeUser/.virtualenvs/pip-testing/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . my_package import main_function
  File "/Users/fakeUser/.virtualenvs/pip-testing/lib/python3.7/site-packages/my_package/my_package.py", line 6, in <module>
    from helpers import helper1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

To resolve this issue, I modified the imports in `my_package.py` to look like this:

```
from .helpers import helper1
from .helpers import helper2
from .helpers import helper3
from .helpers import helper4
```

As far as I understand, python3 uses the `.` to help resolve relative imports. That made sense to try to me because if I am running `my_package.py`, adding the `.` should make it clear that the `helpers` dir is in the same directory as `my_package.py`. Making this modification does in fact resolve the issue for downloading the package from pip, but now introduces the following issue if I were to run this code locally:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_package.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .helpers import helper1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.helpers'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I am trying to understand what's going on here. In particular if someone could explain the following:

- Why does adding the `.` make the code incompatible for local use?
- Why does removing the `.` make the code incompatible for use from pip?

I really want to understand why these imports aren't working to avoid similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original poster here:

The issue was caused by the fact that pip will install the package at level `my_package`, therefore relying on the imports to be setup either as `.helpers` or `my_package.helpers`, whereas running the script `my_package.py` does not install the package, and therefore the imports need to be written differently.

I will mark this is the correct answer asap (I believe that will be tomorrow)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, read up on [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)
The start by using the following pattern

```
my_package
|  README.md
|  LICENSE
|  setup.py
|  build
|  dist
|  src
|  --my_package
|  ---- __init__.py
|  ---- helpers
|  ------__init__.py
|  ------ helper1.py
|  ------ helper2.py
|  ------helper3.py
|  ------helper4.py
```

You can define the top level `__init__.py` empty for now, and the inner `__init__.py` according to how your `helperx.py` looks like, and then when you install the module, you can call helper1 accordingly, for e.g.
`from my_package.helpers import helper1`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my original post, but I actually do have __init__.py files set up as you pointed out; I will edit the original question to include this. I think I actually realized the issue as relating to how pip will install the my_package as an actual package, whereas running a script from inside of my_package has yet to import the package itself and therefore causing the import discrepancies I asked about. I'm going to close the question. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Great, please accept/upvote my answer if it helped you :)